# Does it make sense to gofmt project inside a CI file

Tags: go, continuous-integration

I came across a project which has this line in its gitlab-ci.yml
`go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)` 
which is followed by a go test and then a go build.
The problem is by this point the code is already committed so there is no point in doing a gofmt or am i missing something here.

Comment: Which project? What was the purpose of doing it there?

Comment: it's a private project, the purpose is what i am confused about

Comment: You'll have to look at the context. What happens before and after that command? Is it creating a new commit? Is it generating an error if something changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what the goal is. It may be totally sane to do if a later linter checks whether code is in the proper `gofmt` format and

- they know some forget that and they want to ignore that case for a better experience.
- some generated code is not formatted but also not checked in and so must be gofmt'ed to avoid linter complaints.

Or it just copied over from somewhere else and no one cared to remove it.